# Is it possible to create cloak in the trac wiki?

Tags: wiki, trac

Is it possible to show and hide blocks of content in the trac wiki similar to the  [cloak macro](https://www.adaptavist.com/display/AtlassianConfluence/cloak+macro) of confluential?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a few month old but I was wondering the same thing.
Remy Blank answer put me on the right track, he was just missing an extra div.

```
{{{#!div
{{{#!html
<h3 class="foldable">Section title</h3>
}}}
{{{#!div
This is the section content.
}}}
}}}
```

If you look at the style sheet, it shows you which element gets hidden with the collapsed style.

```
.collapsed > div, .collapsed > table, .collapsed > ul, .collapsed > dl { display: none }
```

Remy's code was wrapping "This is the section content" inside a **p** markup, that's why it wasn't hidden.

Comment: Some credit definitely should go to Remy, but I don't think there is such an option

Comment: You can contact him to edit his answer with my fix and give him all credit (:

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to (temporarily) hide some content while keeping it in the page source, you can use the `{{{#comment}}}` wiki processor. As mentioned by bta, the content is still accessible by downloading the page source, so this is not a security measure.

If you want to collapse a section, and allow users to expand it by clicking, you can use the following trick (tested with 0.12):

```
{{{#!div class=""
{{{#!html
<h3 class="foldable">Section title</h3>
}}}
This is the section content.
}}}
```

This will show the section title with a small triangle on its left, and clicking the title will toggle the section between collapsed and expanded. The section will initially be collapsed.

Comment: i'd like to have a section that a user my collapse and expand, but unfortunately the trick did not work for me. I got a section with a triangle, but it is expanded initially and clicking on it does not change anything. I run track 0.12b1

Answer (score 1):

I'm super late to the party, but the [FoldMacroProcessorMacro](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/FoldMacroProcessorMacro) lets you do this without resorting to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The current versions of Trac do not have permissions this fine-grained.  User accounts can be granted wiki access, but it's an all-or-nothing setting.  The raw wiki-format version of a wiki page can be downloaded in plain text using the links at the bottom of the wiki page, so a macro like this wouldn't really restrict content.

It's possible to write an add-on that blocks access to a particular wiki page based on user account name or permissions, but that's still page-level granularity and not block-level like the macro you mentioned.